# Can I prepare and eat dried oyster mushrooms that are four year old?

Tags: food-safety

Can I prepare and eat dried oyster mushrooms that are four (4) years old?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, certainly. Foods which have been preserved in a permanent way (such as dried mushrooms) are safe to eat in 4 years. The taste can suffer with time, it's up to you to decide if you like them.